# Flow based on Dropdowns selected by SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, email, flow

I have a list of e-mails in 2 different drop-down lists in my SharePoint list and I am trying to send an approval based on the e-mail selected on both drop-downs when the item is created.

How could I get the e-mails selected in a flow in this list and what are the triggers I should use?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger to start the flow would be "When an item is created (SharePoint)".
Current Item's drop down values will be available for use in the flow using the column name as mentioned in the list. Next step would be an action - "Send an email (Office 365 Outlook)". Map the fields and save and run the flow.

Note: Emails will be send from the FLOW CREATOR's account or you can add another in send as field.

Comment: Thank you i just found the columns values when i clicked on "assigned to".